# Form post to Django view renders no input to database

Tags: python, django, forms

So, Im trying to save a todo to a database with django. My template is as follows:

```
<form action="{% url 'todo:add' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" id="text" value="{{new_todo_text}}"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit todo" />
</form>
{%if not_done_todos %}
    <ul>
        {%for todo in not_done_todos%}
            <li>
                <span>{{todo.text}}</span>
            </li>
        {%endfor%}
    </ul>
{%else%}
    <span>No todos for you!</span>
{%endif%}
```

My view where Im trying to catch the "new_todo_text" looks like this:

```
def add(request):
    """Add todo to database"""
    new_todo = Todo(text=request.POST.get('new_todo_text'),
                    done=False, date_created=timezone.now())
    new_todo.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('todo:index'))
```

The problem is that the todo.text turns up empty no matter what I add to the form... whats my problem here?

Comment: You really should learn about django's forms and modelforms...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that inside your `input` element you have not declared a `name` attribute. That `name` attibute will be used as a key to fetch it with Django `request.POST`.

So, change to this:

```
<input type="text" id="text" name="new_todo_text" value="{{new_todo_text}}"/>
```

The `request.POST` dict-like will use the `input`'s `name` and `value` to *build* the dict. Then you can do stuff like `request.POST['input_name_here']`.

Comment: Thanks nik! Worked like a charm! :)